# How do I select frequency of a certain value using groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
data.groupby('race/ethnicity')['lunch'].value_counts()
```

On writing this, I get the following output:

```
race/ethnicity  lunch       
group A         standard         53
                free/reduced     36
group B         standard        121
                free/reduced     69
group C         standard        205
                free/reduced    114
group D         standard        167
                free/reduced     95
group E         standard         99
                free/reduced     41
Name: lunch, dtype: int64
```

How do I get only the counts of the 'standard' entries for each group?

Comment: Filter you dataframe prior to groupby for only lunch == 'standard' then groupby.  This will also increase the efficiency of the groupby calculation by not calculating values not needed.  ie.  `data.query('lunch == "standard"').groupby(...rest of the statement here... `

Comment: That was easy... Stupid me. The only thing in this is that there's a really really big line of code. Is there an alternative for this?

Comment: Yes, you can use boolean indexing also, `data[data['lunch'] == 'standard']`.  Break it up into two lines.   data=data.query... or data = data[data['lunch... then do the groupby above.

Comment: Yeah... thanks for the help!